# R Shiny: How can I make multiple elements reactive in add/remove button context?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am creating a shiny app such that when I click on add or remove button, multiple reactive elements are affected.  I have simplified significantly what I am trying to do below.  Basically, we get selectInput() and textInput() boxes side-by-side, such that the textInput() box is populated with the user-chosen result of selectInput() box.  I then have an add button and remove button, such that by clicking the add button, on the next line down, we get new selectInput() and textInput() boxes side-by-side.  As above, the new row's textInput() box displays the user-chosen result of the new row's selectInput() box.

The issue I am having is being able to reference the new value of the new seletInput() box.  Using a get() reference does not work, and I need an iterative way to be able to reference these values as new boxes are added and removed.  How can I successfully call references to the result of successive selectInput() boxes?

```
suppressWarnings(library(shiny))
suppressWarnings(library(shinyFiles))


ui <- function(request) {
    fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            column(2,
                uiOutput("ui1")
            ),
            column(2,
                uiOutput("ui2")
            ),
            column(1,
                actionButton(inputId = 'insertParamBtn', label = "Add Param")
            ),
            column(1,
                actionButton(inputId = 'removeParamBtn', label = "Remove Param")
            )
            ),
        tags$div(id = 'placeholder'),
        hr(),
        fluidRow(column(12, verbatimTextOutput("view", placeholder = T)))
            )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    params <- reactiveValues(btn = 0)
    output$ui1 <- renderUI({
        selectInput("UI1", "First UI",
            choices = thisList, selected = 1)
    })
    output$ui2 <- renderUI({
        textInput("UI2", "Second UI", value = input$UI1, width = '150px')
    })

    observeEvent(input$insertParamBtn, {
        params$btn <- params$btn + 1
        insertUI(
            selector = '#placeholder',
        ## wrap element in a div with id for ease of removal
            ui = tags$div(
                id = paste0('param', params$btn + 1),
                    tags$p(fluidRow(
                        column(2,
                            selectInput(paste0("UI1", params$btn + 1),
                                        paste0("First UI ", params$btn + 1),
                                        choices = thisList, selected = 1)
                                ),
                        column(2,
                            textInput(paste0("UI2", params$btn + 1),  #*#
                                paste0("Second UI ", params$btn + 1),  #*#
                                value = get(paste0("input$UI1", params$btn + 1)),  #*#
                                    width = '150px')    #*#
                                )
                                )
                            )
                            )
                            )
    output$view <- renderPrint({ get(paste0("UI1", params$btn + 1)) })
    })

    observeEvent(input$removeParamBtn, {
    removeUI(
    ## pass in appropriate div id
            selector = paste0('#param', params$btn + 1)
                )
    params$btn <- params$btn - 1
    })

    }
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem in your code. The object `thislist` is nowhere defined but it is used twice in the app.

Comment: thisList <- as.list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy that line first.  Thanks for heads up

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but the following approach adds/removes input pairs via two buttrons. First, I created a [shiny module](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) for the selection-duo

```
thisList <- as.list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) 

suppressWarnings(library(shiny))

selectorUI <- function(id){
  ns = NS(id)

  tags$div(
    fluidRow(
      column(6, uiOutput(ns('first'))),
      column(6, uiOutput(ns('second')))
    ),
    id = paste0('param', id)
  )
}

selectorServer <- function(input, output, session){
  ns = session$ns

  output$first <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      ns('first'),
      ns("First UI"),
      choices = thisList, selected = 1)
  })

  output$second <- renderUI({
    textInput(
      ns('second'),
      ns("Second UI"),
      value = input$first)
  })
}
```

The new ui already uses `selectorUI`: the ui side function of the module.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectorUI(0),
  fluidRow(
    column(6, actionButton(inputId = 'insertParamBtn', label = "Add Param")),
    column(6, actionButton(inputId = 'removeParamBtn', label = "Remove Param"))
  ),
  tags$div(id = 'placeholder'),
  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(12, verbatimTextOutput("view", placeholder = T)))
)
```

The server side renders the module for `id=0` at startup and for `id=params$button` whenever a new row is added.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(selectorServer, 0)

  params <- reactiveValues(btn = 0)

  output$view <- renderPrint({ 
    print(input[[NS(params$btn, "first")]])
    print(input[[NS(params$btn, "second")]])
  })

  observeEvent(input$insertParamBtn, {
    params$btn <- params$btn + 1
    callModule(selectorServer, params$btn)
    insertUI(
      selector = '#placeholder',
      ui = selectorUI(params$btn)
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$removeParamBtn, {
    removeUI(
      ## pass in appropriate div id
      selector = paste0('#param', params$btn)
    )
    params$btn <- params$btn - 1
  })      
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The key difference to your code is that I used two seperate `renderUI` calls for the `selectInput` and the `textInput`. Putting those two in one single `renderUI` call can create infinite loops if you are not careful.

The fact that I rewrote this using models is just a design decision that makes the code easier to read and extend IMO.