# is it possible to nest dynamic accordions in a shiny app?

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, accordion

Following a previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60072174/12812645 , I am trying to nest dynamic accordions in a shiny app.

As you can see on the example below, nothing happen when clicking on the "+" actionLink (created by insertUI). I tried to debug inserting a browser() inside the observeEvent function of this action Link and the R console print the following message in response to insertUI:

```
function () 
{
    .callbacks$remove(id)
}
<environment: 0x00000000138245b8>
```

What does this mean ?

here is the code of the shiny app I would like to fix :

```
library(shiny)
library(dqshiny)

selectorUI <- function(id){
  ns = NS(id)

  tags$div(
    fluidRow(
      column(6, uiOutput(ns('new_ui')))
    ),
    id = paste0('ui', id)
  )
}

selectorServer <- function(input, output, session){
  ns = session$ns

  output$new_ui <- render_dq_box_group({
    dq_accordion(ns("foo"), 
                 titles = ns("input"), 
                 contents = list(textInput(inputId = ns("txt"),
                                           label = "")),
                 bg_color = NULL, 
                 options = list(animate = 200, collapsible = TRUE),
                 icons = c(open = "hand-point-down", closed = "hand-point-right")
    )
  })
}

  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      actionButton("add", "+"),
      selectorUI(1),
      selectorUI(2),
      selectorUI(3),
      tags$div(id = 'placeholder'),
      actionButton("delete", "-")
    )
  )

  server = function(input, output) {

    callModule(selectorServer, 1)
    callModule(selectorServer, 2)
    callModule(selectorServer, 3)

    counter <- reactiveValues(value = 3) # number of inputs already present

    observeEvent(input$add, {

      counter$value <- counter$value + 1

      insertUI(
        selector = "#placeholder",
        ui = selectorUI(counter$value)
      )
      callModule(selectorServer, counter$value)

      insertUI(
        selector = "#placeholder",
        ui =  tagList(
          actionLink(paste0("add",counter$value), "+"),
          tags$div(id = paste0('placeholder',counter$value))
        )
      )

    })

    observeEvent(input$delete, {
      removeUI(
        selector = paste0("#ui", counter$value)
      )
      counter$value <- counter$value - 1
    })

    observeEvent(input[[paste0("add",counter$value)]], {

      counter$value <- counter$value + 1
      insertUI(
        selector = paste0("#placeholder",counter$value),
        ui = selectorUI(counter$value)
      )
      callModule(selectorServer, counter$value)

    })

  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edit : after several tries I can't figure it out :-/ 
Does anyone have any idea where I might be looking? Thanks